# How can I dim the content with a semitransparent overlay when hovering a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to programming and currently working on my portfolio. I've created a dropdown list that appears when a user hovers over it. Once it appears I want to make the rest of the website darker so the dropdown list can stand out from the rest.

I'm trying to use the body::after pseudo class for that and it works but not when I hover over the dropdown so I must be doing something wrong. Could anyone please help me?

The dropdown list has a class of `.dropdown`

```
  body::after {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

 .dropdown:hover body::after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Link to my project in case that helps:
https://annaxt.github.io/product_landing_page/plant_store.html

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: By the way Anna, nice design. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the overlay as it's own element and then control the opacity using JavaScript. Everything you would want to show above it would need to have a z-index higher than what you're setting on the overlay and everything that would be affected by the overlay should have a lower z-index (default is 0).

```js
let overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
function showOverlay() {
  overlay.style.zindex = 9;
  overlay.style.opacity = 0.3;
}

function hideOverlay() {
  overlay.style.zindex = -1;
  overlay.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

```css
#overlay {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: opacity .8s;
}

.dropdown {
  font-size: 50px;
  background: #369;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dropdown" onmouseout="hideOverlay()" onmouseover="showOverlay()">Hover me</div>
  <div id="overlay" />
</body>
```

Comment: This is probably the way to go, but might be helpful to explain the problem OP has with the `.dropdown:hover body::after` selector just to make it clear.

Comment: Feel free to edit and improve the answer. I need to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether we can do this with css or not. but what you are trying to achieve can be easily done by js.
Below is code to help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown").mouseenter(function() {
    $("body").addClass("open");
  });
  $(".dropdown").mouseleave(function() {
    $("body").removeClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.open {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #232323;
  transition:.5s;
}

.dropdown {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  transition:.5s;
}
.main:hover .dropdown{
  filter:blur(1px);
}
.main:hover .dropdown:hover {
  background-color: red;
  filter:blur(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="dropdown">
    dropdown1
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    dropdown2
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    dropdown3
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    dropdown4
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's actually way easier with JavaScript!